# database seeded error while seed data with foreignkey in laravel

Tags: php, database, foreign-keys, laravel-4, foreign-key-relationship

When i seed data,with foreign key exists in table then following error occur..i can't solve this, How can i solve??

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update   
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`doctodoor2014`.`staffs`,
CONSTRAINT `staffs_specialty_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`specialty_id`) REFERENCES
specialties` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `staffs` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`)
values (1, Admin, Admin))
```

can i seed table with foreign keys??

Comment: Not familiar with laravel, but seed specialities first is what you should be looking for.

Comment: you would need to see the referenced table first, then seed the table with the foreign key(s)

Comment: Most likely you are seeding in the wrong order.

Comment: @warspite i do the same way u suggest, i first seed the reference table data then after seed the foreign key table,but entry exists into reference table but not into the foreign key table,when i seed data into the foreign key table, error displayed as i post question..

Comment: @TonyHopkinson i want to seed data into the table but in my table foreign key exists.nd that displayed Error like my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can seed with foreign keys. You just need to ensure the parent exists before inserting the child.
Look at the contents of the two tables in question, and see if parent id exists for the given child id that your are trying to insert.

I found that my problem was I was that every time I ran my seed classes, the id's of parent tables would increment. Because my child table inserts had hardcoded id's, I'd get a referential integrity error.

As a quick work around, you could drop the database and recreate it, which would reset all of the `autoincrementing` id's.

Better to fix your seed definitions though of course. I did this by replacing my hardcoded id's in the child table with the actual parent id as follows:

```
//,'user_id'=>1 
  ,'user_id'=>User::first()->id
```

To help with debugging - add `echo` statement at the start and end of each seed class to help see where the error is.

```
public function run() {
  echo PHP_EOL.'QuestionTableSeeder BEGIN'.PHP_EOL;
  $test_id = Test::first()->id;
  echo PHP_EOL."test_id:'" . $test_id. "'";

  ...
  echo PHP_EOL.'QuestionTableSeeder END'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Another thing that tripped me up was that I was calling:

```
  User::first()->id
```

which was returning an empty string.
Turns out, it was actually meant to be:

```
  User::first()->user_id
```

The table was created by another developer who didn't follow the convention of naming primary keys as id!